# Glutamate substitute for ALS?

Tags: glucose

I was just reading up on some ALS literature, and noted something on a newly diagnosed patient. The (current) assessment is that this particular patient's ALS symptoms are caused by a glutamate deficiency. What is interesting is that the patient is a Type 2 diabetic, which would hint at that as an original source for the deficiency, as glutamate is typically synthesized in cells from glucose. But glutamate can also be synthesized, in cells, from aspartate, as in aspartame. The patient claims to have stopped drinking sugar-free beverages about a year ago, for personal reasons, which roughly lines up with the onset of the symptoms. Could it be that the patient has been unknowingly substituting glucose-to-glutamate synthesis with aspartate-to-glutamate synthesis and the change in diet stopped that? And is it maybe possible to add aspartame products to the diet and get that work-around running again, to reduce glutamate deficiency symptoms?

I sadly lack access to ALS experts around here, so I thought this could be a place to ask.